# Normal subgroup of $GLn(\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is  the   subgroup of all complex  orthogonal matrix  are  normal subgroup of $GLn(\mathbb{C})$ ?

My attempt :  I know  that  in  real orthogonal matrix  its is false  take  $A=  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\-1 &0 \end{bmatrix}$ , $P=  \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0\\0 &1 \end{bmatrix}$ that is $PAP^{-1} = B$ .Here $BB^T\neq  I$

Im confused in  complex  field

Any hints/solution

Comment: Your attempt makes no sense.  It is not clear what your example has to do with normal subgroups.

Comment: oksss@Omnomnomnom  i just try to contradict the  statement in real orh=thogonal matrix

Comment: The statement is that every subgroup is normal.  What is the subgroup that you have defined, and how have you shown that it is not normal?

Comment: actually i  try to conjugating  some orthogonal matrix @Omnomnomnom here $A \in O(2)$

Comment: I can see that this is what you have done.  My question is what conjugating some orthogonal matrix has to do with normal subgroups of the set of orthogonal matrices (we can stick to real-orthogonal matrices for now).  It seems as though you do not understand the question being asked.

Comment: now that you've written your question clearly, your attempt makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For instance, $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ is not a normal subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$. To see why when $n=2$, use the fact that, say,$$\begin{bmatrix}1+i&i\\i&1-i\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&3\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}1+i&i\\i&1-i\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}3&2i\\-2i&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: The question seems to be about subgroups of the group of complex-orthogonal matrices

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Let us see what Jasmine has to say about this.

Comment: thanks u  @JoséCarlosSantos sir

Comment: i have  edited  my  question@Omnomnomnom

Comment: I am glad that the asker considers their question answered, but I don't see how this example answers the question; maybe I'm missing something.  What does $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ failing to be a normal subgroup of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$ have to do with the complex-orthogonal matrices failing to be a normal subgroup of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for the real case works for the complex case as well.  You have an orthogonal matrix $A$ and a matrix $P \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$ such that $A$ is complex-orthogonal (i.e. it satisfies $AA^T = I$), but $PAP^{-1}$ is not complex orthogonal.

Normal subgroups must be closed under conjugation, so the complex-orthogonal matrices do not form a normal subgroup.